# Navigation Component - anyway implement swipe to back like iOS?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I have an application designed by Navigation Component. In my app, i have one MainActivity include a nav_graph (called main_nav_graph) has a lot of fragment. My fragments use navController.navigate() and navController.popBackStack() to move between them.
Now i want to make a feature that i can swipe (from left edge of device screen to center horizontal screen) to back from current fragment to previous fragment. Ex like telegram or slack.
I was research for this a few times but i didn't found solution for myself. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can implement this functionality by putting a clickable transparent view (positioned on the left with 20% width of the parent) and implementing a gesture detector for detecting left to right swipe action. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down-in-android

Answer (score 0):

#### Navigation library

I wrote a library fully integrated with NavComponent. It's exactly what you were looking for. Note that it works only with fragments, so it is not possible to achieve the same behavior with activities.

https://github.com/massivemadness/Fragula

[image]

The navigation API stays the same, you should only make some changes in your NavGraph and NavHost container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not what I need. I found a lot of such lib on github but none of them handle for activities and fragments both.